# GWT force scroll panel to render on manual scroll (with video describing situation)

Tags: java, html, gwt, drag-and-drop, scroll

I'm having trouble manually scrolling of a scrollPanel.
The picture below display 3 situations:

I have two side by side grids that I have manually made using tree and [gwtqueryplugins](http://code.google.com/p/gwtquery-plugins/wiki/DragAndDropPluginForGWTDeveloppers) because of drag and drop options and other stuff not worth explaining here.

[image]

I want to drag elements between grids. 
On case (**1**) nothing is happening. 
On case (**2**) I'm dragging an element from grid 2 (with name Teresa) over the element on grid 1 which becomes red.
So far everything works ok. 
Now, on case(**3**) it's when I have trouble. When the panels indicated by the arrows, have a draggable over them, a scroll event is fired on the grid. After scrolling the grid, I want to drag my Paulo draggable over Cristina. But as you can see, Cristina is only hovered when Paulo is much below the actual position.

If I leave the browser page (causing a scroll to appear on the main page) and come back to "Cristina" it'll be ok. This makes me believe the HTML is not rendered until I finally drop the draggable element or when the page is forced to be re-rendered and therefore references the droppable object in its old position...

**Watch [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8v1ucBxcnbs) a video for a full understanding of the problem**

Comment: Could you please explain a little bit more about last case? At what moment scroll event is appears? While you are dragging the user?

Comment: Both grids are equal in behavior. Only contain different users. When I'm dragging the user over the grey panel indicated by the arrow (the footer), for this case on the first grid, I manually scroll that grid down (scrollPanel.setScrollPosition.....). Once I do that I can only hove over Cristina when I'm further down (as the image 3 shows). If I take the draggable out of the browser window, when I get back at Cristina it works fine. :/

Comment: Got it. Agree, it really seems that old positions of droppable elements are stored somewhere and should be refreshed.

Comment: Hence the question. Do you think of anyway to refresh the html code without forcing the user do hackings like take the draggable out of the browser window and get back?

Comment: You can try to call layoutContainer.layout(true/* force */); on required layout container.

Comment: I'll try that. Anyway, I updated my question with a video for the problem. Just to make the problem clearer. :) Thank you very much.

Comment: hum... which panel/widget has that method? I can't find such thing. :/

Comment: That looks like a GWT EXT method, right? :/

Comment: Yes, sorry, I am talking about GXT containers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the scroll plugin doesn't handle your event when you manually scroll the area. However, it does handle the case when you drag out of the window.

Normally, it should re-initialize all droppables. As a workaround, you can do it manually - just after you scroll the area:

```
DragAndDropManager.getInstance().initialize(draggableLabel.getElement(), null);
```

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you! weeks trying to find something like this! :) Thank you.